# VSCode multiple import statements for different methods from the same library

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, import

For a while intelliSense was working fine, so if I auto-imported different methods from the same library, it was doing it in one line like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react`;
```

Recently when auto importing methods, it results in:

```
import React from 'react`;
import { useState } from 'react`;
import { useEffect } from 'react`;
```

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Add a language tag. JS, I assume?

Comment: it does not look like Haskell or Python